# Trick PC into having a physical and virtual DVD Drive

Tags: virtual-machine, dvd, iso-image, windows-server-2012-r2

At school, I've got a server running to which I can make a VPN. Now, I need to set up a few VM's with all having a need for a different OS.

I can't physically go to school to change a boot DVD, so I need a way to trick that server into thinking it has two DVD drives plugged into it. One is a physical one, the other (preferably) a mounted ISO file, so I can use both as boot DVD for the different VM's. (Say Ubuntu Server for some ones and Windows 7 for others).

Is there any way of doing this?

Regards

Comment: Your VM software should be able to directly mount a ISO.

Comment: Tricking the PC into thinking it has a physical drive makes it a virtual drive by definition. Is there any reason you need a physical one instead of using multiple virtual drives for different VMs?

Comment: I tried to mount an ISO directly, and that didn't work, that's why I asked this question, although this time I was able to successfully mount one.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a rather silly way to handle it. Well, you could install some arbitrary image mounting software (and windows 10 and its equivilent windows server release would do this natively) *but* almost all VM software should be able to mount an ISO for installation natively. In the case of many 'server' grade VM hosts, you might even be able to do this remotely.

In short, what you want to do shouldn't be necessary, and no trickery is needed.